# How to get the concat result on alert() as string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to get the concat result on alert(), which is stored in the variable FavAppnd,

Tested

```
alert (FavAppnd);//returns object Object

alert (FavAppnd.toString());//returns object Object

alert (JSON.stringify(FavAppnd));//returns {"0":{},"length":1}
```

But I want like this in html pattern on `alert()----`
As the html tags are dynamically created, page source option on browser does not display the html tags on runtime.So to verify I want it on `alert()`.

```
<tr>
<td>ABC</td>
<td><img src="images/star1.png" onclick="changeStar(this)" width="32" height="32" id=0></td>
</tr>
```

HTML

```
<table id="favicon" border="1">

</table>
```

JS

```
    function favShow()
    {

        var invocationFav={
                adapter:"SQL_ADAPTER_1",
                procedure:"procedureFavoriteShow",
                parameters:[]
               };

    var options={
            onSuccess:succFavShow,
            onFailure:failFavShow
            };
    WL.Client.invokeProcedure(invocationFav,options);
    }
        function succFavShow(result)
        {
        var a=result.invocationResult.resultSet.length;
         if(a>0)
            {
        alert("FavShow success");
            var Favlist = $("#favicon");
                for(var i=0;i<a;i++)
                {

                    var FavAppnd=$('<tr><td>'+name+'</td>'+'<td>'+'<img src="images/star1.png" onclick="changeStar(this)" width="32" height="32" id='+id+'></td></tr>');
                    Favlist.append(FavAppnd);

                    alert (FavAppnd);//returns object Object
                    alert (FavAppnd.toString());//returns object Object
                    alert (JSON.stringify(FavAppnd));//returns {"0":{},"length":1}
                }
        }
            else
                {
                alert("Favorite not available");
                }
        }
function failFavShow()
{
 alert("try again");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're solving the wrong problem. Instead of using `alert`, why not use `console.log` instead? Gives you a more detailed breakdown of the object you're trying to inspect.

With regard to your question, `FavAppnd` is a jQuery object. You can do `FavAppnd.wrap('<div/>').parent().html()`. `wrap` is needed since `.html()` returns the HTML representation of the object but excludes the top element. We everything in a `<div>` so that the `<div>` is the one excluded.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.html()`](https://api.jquery.com/html/) or [`.text`](https://api.jquery.com/text/), like so

```
FavAppnd.html()
FavAppnd.text()
```